# updating the value of a variable inside of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Every time I try to use the variable `i` in the function `modulus`, it sets the variable to equal 0.

I tried using the line of code: `newi = i`, but that didn't work because `i` was already equal to 0. I tried `i = i` in the modulus function, but that also didn't work. I've tried defining both `i` and `a` at the top of the program, that didn't work. I'm expecting `i` to change by running the `primeChecker` function, but the value becomes 0. I have no idea why it is 0 because I did not set `i = 0` anywhere in my code.

Code:

```
number = input("How many numbers? ")
intnumber = int(number)
modulus = {}
modulusCounter = 0
exceptionPrime = [2]
prime = [3, 5, 7]
print("lengthprime", len(prime))

def modulus(i, a):
    print("i:", i)
    print(prime)
    print("modulus", prime[a])
    i % (prime[a])

def primeChecker(i, a, prime, modulusCounter):
    print("2 check")
    print("a value: ", a)
    print("prime: ", len(prime))

    for a in range(len(prime)):
        print("3 check")
        print("a: " + str(a))
        print("lengthprime: ", len(prime))

        if modulus(i,a) == 0:
            i += 2
            modulusCounter += 1
            print("1 check")

        else: #elif modulus(a,i) != 0:
            a += 1
            print("2 check")

    if a == len(prime) and modulusCounter == 0:
        print("Prime: ", i)
        print("3 check")
        prime.append(i)         
        i += 1
        modulusCounter = 0          
        a = 0

i = 3
a = 0

for i in range(intnumber):
    print("1 check")
    primeChecker(i, a, prime, modulusCounter)

print(prime)
```

Comment: The last line of `modulus` doesn't do anything useful. `i` itself isn't changed, and you don't do anything with the value of the expression.

Comment: `modulus` isn't returning anything

Comment: Certainly the first time through: `for i in range(intnumber)` this sets `i=0`

Comment: How do I return something from a function?

Comment: Use the  `return`  keyword?

Comment: @quamrana no I meant, what value do I return to? Like do I type, "return primeChecker"?

Comment: What? `"How do I return something from a function?"` just `return something`

Comment: @quamrana, so it doesn't matter what I return? I could type "return peanutButter" and that would work?

Comment: Well, yes, if `peanutButter` is a variable inside your function.

Answer (score 1):

```
...  

i = 3
a = 0
    
for i in range(intnumber):
    print("1 check")
    primeChecker(i, a, prime, modulusCounter)

...
```

The "for" loop is setting i to 0. You can see for yourself by adding print statements

```
...
i = 3
a = 0

print(i)

for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    # ...your code

print(i)
...
```

Comment: Which leads to a useful rule: never reuse your variable names.  For loop counters that you don't need to refer to anywhere in the code, a helpful convention is to use `for _ in ...`.